# How to get specific type of files from a specific directory in a given path in an array in c#?

Tags: c#

How do I get all *.txt files from a folder path to an array where I only want to get all the *.txt files from that specificly belong to a sub-directory called TXT.
I have tried

```
string[] txtFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\MyFiles", "*.txt");
```

But the above code gets all *.txt files in the given directory instead of those that are in the sub-folder named TXT?
The folders inside MyFiles look like below:

```
152-10-11
30-124-12
....
```

Where each of the folders `152-10-11` has sub-folders like `152\10\11\TXT`

Comment: use path `@"D:\MyFiles\TXT"`?

Comment: Well, the sub-folder txt is inside multiple sub-directories in D:\MyFiles

Comment: @Bumba, could you include a screenshot of the directory structure you have? It doesn't make a whole lot of sense at the moment.

Comment: You didnt state that in your question.

Why not just add the sub-directories to the path then:

`@"D:\MyFiles\Sub1\Sub2\TXT"`

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles("@D:\MyFiles", "*.txt", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)`

Comment: Well, the folders inside MyFiles look like
`1235-12-3053,
12303-12-3,
123560-55913-136` and each of them have subfolders like `1235/12/3053/TXT`

Comment: @Bumba, maybe implement 2-step process: 1. find full path to "TXT" folder 2. search .txt files using that fullpath ?

Comment: @Bumba you need to updated your *question* with that information about the sub-folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for a specific directory using (assuming that you only have one directory that starts with "TXT"):

```
    string[] txtDir = Directory.GetDirectories(@"D:\", "TXT*");
```

You could then use that result to get the files:

```
    string[] txtFiles = Directory.GetFiles(txtDir[0], "*.txt");
```

Comment: Each folders in MyPath have only one TXT sub-folder in them. Will your code work with that?

Comment: @Bumba With the code I supplied, if you have more than 1 folder named "TXT", this will pull back all of the folder and their paths with that name. If you have a more specific directory, you will need to further narrow down the directory search by including sub folders in the search path, as such: `string[] txtDir = Directory.GetDirectories(@"D:\SubFolder", "TXT*");`

Comment: @Bumba, in the directory structure `152\10\11\TXT`, provided that there is only a single "TXT" folder, and that `152\TXT` or  `152\10\TXT` don't exist, the following code will work: `string[] txtDir = Directory.GetDirectories(@"D:\152\", "TXT*");`